# ReferenceError: auth is not defined nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've created a puppy database using My SQL workbench, I am not developing multiples routers that allow me to view all puppies, add a puppy, update a puppy etc. I am currently working on the router to delete a puppy. However, I keep getting a 'ReferenceError: auth is not defined' error.

Here is my code for the router.delete:

```
    try {
        const puppyID = req.params.id;
        const token = await auth.verify('puppy.remove', req);
        await puppyCtrl.removePuppy(puppyID, token.id);
        res.json({ message: 'Puppy Removed Successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ message: "Failed to delete puppy" });
    }
});
```

I am testing it on Postman and get the "Failed to delete puppy" error on postman. So it does get to the catch. However, I think there is probably an error within my try statement.

Comment: Is the error message not clear to you? `auth` has not been declared. If you want to use it you have to declare it and initialize it with the right value.

Comment: You use auth on the 3rd line but you probably didn't declare or import it.